# How do I change the delimiter of a list?

Tags: php, explode

```
$variable = 'one, two, three';
```

How can I replace the commas between words with `<br>`?

`$variable` should become:

```
one<br>
two<br>
three
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either use `str_replace`:

```
$variable = str_replace(", ", "<br>", $variable);
```

or, if you want to do other things with the elements in between, `explode()` and `implode()`:

```
$variable_exploded = explode(", ", $variable);
$variable_imploded = implode("<br>", $variable_exploded);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$variable = str_replace(", ","<br>\n",$variable);
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
$variable = explode(', ',$variable);
$variable = implode("<br/>\n",$variable);
```

You can then just `echo $variable`

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$variable = str_replace(', ',"<br>\n",$variable);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$variable = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', "<br>\n", $variable);
```

This takes you into regex land but this will handle cases of random spacing between commas, e.g.

```
$variable = 'one,two, three';
```

or

```
$variable = 'one , two, three';
```